# "Your computer restarted because of a problem mac" almost everyday

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

Almost once a day my mac restarts because of a problem, and I have no idea what the problem could be. Could it be the RAM? I have 8 GB of ram and I usually use 6-7 GB of it.

This is the report that i get:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8003f732ca): "Element 0xffffff80184da720 from zone kalloc.48 caught being freed to wrong zone NFSV3 diroff\n"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.141.2/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:3961
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9136f639c0 : 0xffffff8003f1a65d 
0xffffff9136f63a10 : 0xffffff8004054a75 
0xffffff9136f63a50 : 0xffffff80040465fe 
0xffffff9136f63aa0 : 0xffffff8003ec0a40 
0xffffff9136f63ac0 : 0xffffff8003f19d27 
0xffffff9136f63bc0 : 0xffffff8003f1a117 
0xffffff9136f63c10 : 0xffffff80046c1a6c 
0xffffff9136f63c80 : 0xffffff8003f732ca 
0xffffff9136f63d70 : 0xffffff80040c3486 
0xffffff9136f63e60 : 0xffffff8004174a08 
0xffffff9136f63ee0 : 0xffffff800417419f 
0xffffff9136f63f40 : 0xffffff8004175532 
0xffffff9136f63f70 : 0xffffff800417542a 
0xffffff9136f63fa0 : 0xffffff8003ec013e 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19H2

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Aug 31 22:12:52 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 05D51A3D-3A87-3FF0-98C3-9CF3827A3EDD
Kernel slide:     0x0000000003c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8003e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8003d00000
System model name: MacBookAir7,2 (Mac-937CB26E2E02BB01)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 48531011482809
last loaded kext at 2300371919070: >!AXsanScheme    3 (addr 0xffffff7f87a32000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 1498773628946: >!AXsanScheme  3 (addr 0xffffff7f87952000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
@filesystems.afpfs  11.2
@nke.asp-tcp    8.1
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4.4
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.6
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.6
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f7
>!ABacklight    180.3
>pmtelemetry    1
>!A!IBDWGraphics    14.0.7
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>eficheck   1
>!ALPC  3.1
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.7
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!UCardReader   489.120.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.1
>!AAHCIPort 341.140.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!UAudio    323.4
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
$SecureRemotePassword   1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.6
|IOAVB!F    850.1
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.6
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.6
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.3
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.6f7
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.6f7
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f7
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f7
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f7
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f7
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   59
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>!AHSSPISupport 59
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```